# Auto refresh images in HTML

Tags: javascript, html

I am using following code

```
<html>
<script>

    var newImage = new Image();

function updateImage() {
    if(newImage.complete) {
           newImage.src = document.getElementById("img").src;
           var temp = newImage.src;
           document.getElementById("img").src = newImage.src;
           newImage = new Image();
           newImage.src = temp+"?" + new Date().getTime();

}
setTimeout(updateImage, 1000);
};
</script>

<body onload="updateImage();">
<img id="img" src="http://cameraURI" style="position:absolute;top:0;left:0;height:50%;width:50%"/>
</body>
</html>
```

But my image is not getting refreshed. Note that for my application purpose, I cant use any url in script.

I know I need to remove  `newImage.src = document.getElementById("img").src;` and need to place over `function updateImage()` in same file but if I do this, I am getting error as `document.getElementById(" ").src is set to NULL` and I cant use auto-refresh HTML page. So any help on this file??

Comment: change element id istead of using img

Comment: @SridharR: I tried still same problem..

Comment: add <head> tags in the head, right after html

Comment: @caramba: No error after adding <head> but still image is not getting refreshed..

Comment: `newImage` loads the new image correctly, but is never used. See my answer for more explanation and working, simple code.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

try this

```
function refresh(node)
{
   var times = 3000; // gap in Milli Seconds;

   (function startRefresh()
   {
      var address;
      if(node.src.indexOf('?')>-1)
       address = node.src.split('?')[0];
      else 
       address = node.src;
      node.src = address+"?time="+new Date().getTime();

      setTimeout(startRefresh,times);
   })();

}

window.onload = function()
{
  var node = document.getElementById('img');
  refresh(node);
  // you can refresh as many images you want just repeat above steps
}
```

Answer (score 17):

Your code doesn't work because `newImage` is never used. The `src` of `newImage` changes correctly, and the new image will, in fact, be successfully loaded, but `newImage` is never inserted into the HTML.

This is the simplest way to do what you want:

```
window.onload = function() {
    var image = document.getElementById("img");

    function updateImage() {
        image.src = image.src.split("?")[0] + "?" + new Date().getTime();
    }

    setInterval(updateImage, 1000);
}
```

This code

- Uses `setInterval()` instead of `setTimeout()`, since this is a repeated task
- Alters the image's `src` attribute directly - no extra variable needed (i.e. `newImage`)
- Does not require inline event handlers for any element

Comment: Move "var image = document.getElementById("img");" inside window.onload(), as element with ID "img" might not yet be defined when the javascript is executed, typically if in the HTML <head>.

Comment: @François thanks! Good correction. (I moved all of the code to `window.onload()`)

Answer (score 0):

There's supposedly a one-line solution at http://snipplr.com/view/17272/single-line-image-refresh/

Needs a little cleanup at least, when I copy and paste I get
<img src=â€image.jpgâ€ id=â€reloaderâ€ onload=â€setTimeout(â€™document.getElementById(\â€™reloader\â€™).src=\â€™image.jpg?\â€™+new Date().getMilliseconds()â€™, 5000)â€ />

This version at least gives less errors:

`<img src="test2.jpg" id="reloader"
onLoad="setTimeout(document.getElementById('reloader').src='test2.jpg' ? +new Date().getMilliseconds(),5000)"/>`

Double quote at the outermost (onLoad) level, singles inside those.

Nope, sorry, can't make it actually work.  I'm using gphoto to get the viewfinder image from a camera,  I was hoping to have that served over Apache on the machine that's running on.  If I manually hit reload on the web page I see the image change, but it's not happening at the setTimeout interval.  If I get it to work eventually I'll edit this, I saved the URL.

Left out the ?, now the image just doesn't change except when I reload the page.

Maybe something is wrong with my conversion of the quoting.  In the original I think I see 3 different quote symbols, are they using backticks too? â€, â€™, and \â€™.  The charset is supposed to be utf-8 by the page source but something broke somewhere.  At least my Firefox shows junk that I'm trying to guess what it means.

Answer (score 0):

This will fix the syntax on Alan Corey's message above (thanks Alan!)...and I tested it and it works great!

`<img src="test2.jpg" id="reloader" onLoad="setTimeout( () => { document.getElementById('reloader').src='test2.jpg' + '?' + new Date().getMilliseconds() } ,5000)" />`